# Draw many controls quickly using async?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I have a windows form with many controls on it (mainly text boxes and buttons). Every time I chance the size of the form I change the size and position of the controls so that they are nicely distributed over the form. **The problem is that when I change the size of the form it takes up to half a second to redraw all the controls. How can I speed this up?**

I have used `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to time my code and I think that the part that is taking a long time is actually the drawing of the controls on screen (since the math I am doing is completed in less than a millisecond). I have also optimized it so controls are only redrawn when necessary.

One idea I had was to use async functions to draw the controls using several different threads but I don't know much about how forms draw their controls so I don't know if this is possible. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570336/c-sharp-asynchronous-drawing-on-a-panel) question seems to indicate it's not possible to draw controls from another thread. (I have also never used async programming before and am not sure how I would do it so if this is possible any pointers would be appreciated).

My main questions are:

- **Is it possible to use async programming to do this?**
- **Is there another/better way?**

Comment: Do you really have to use WinForms? If you used WPF, all of what you want to achieve would be done automatically.

Comment: @Xaver this is a past school project that I am turning into a personal project and I have no experience in WPF. I will take a look at that but depending on the learning curve it might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Take a look at the Form's `SuspendLayout`, `ResumeLayout` and `PerformLayout` methods.  That's why they exist.  You *suspend*, move everything around, *resume* and then *perform* it all at once

Comment: I have tried `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` with no success but maybe that's because I wasn't using `PerformLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the UI-thread can update the UI. Therefore multitasking cannot be used to speed up drawing to the UI.

Try setting `DoubleBuffered = true;` in the form after `InitializeComponent();`. Sometimes this helps. This setting is often used to reduce flicker.

Are you trying to distribute the controls programmatically? You can use the `Anchor` property to have winforms do this automatically for you. There is also a `FlowLayoutPanel` and a `TableLayoutPanel`. These panels are very helpful for automatic layouts. Even the `SplitContainer` can be useful for layouting.

If you are making changes to the UI, you can also try to suspend winforms' layouting. This prevents winforms from doing unnecessary calculations and drawing.

```
SuspendLayout();
try {
    // TODO: Your positioning and sizing logic
} finally {
    ResumeLayout();
}
```

The try-finally ensures that `ResumeLayout` runs even in case of an exception, or when you leave the code block with `return`.

Comment: I will try DoubleBuffer. I have been distributing them programmatically (there are a few fancier things I am doing with controls stretching non-linearly) but I could try some of the methods you mentioned.